# User Created Thread Pool Shutdown having different behaviour when a sysout is added

Tags: java, multithreading

I was asked to create my own thread pool in an interview where I have to create the number of threads requested by the user. Allow user to submit there task and finally shutdown the pool. I wrote the below program which is working fine in all the cases other than shutdown.

```
public class ThreadPool
{ 
public final Queue<Runnable> workerQueue;
private static boolean isrunning = true;
private Thread[] workerThreads;


public ThreadPool(int N)
{
    workerQueue = new LinkedList<>();
    workerThreads = new Thread[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        workerThreads[i] = new Worker("Pool Thread " + i);
        workerThreads[i].start();
    }
}

public void shutdown()
{
    while(isrunning){
        if(workerQueue.isEmpty()){

            isrunning = false;
        }
    }
}

public void  submit(Runnable r) throws Exception
{
        workerQueue.add(r);
}

private class Worker extends Thread
{
    public Worker(String name)
    {
        super(name);
    }

    public void run()
    {
        while (isrunning) {
            try {
                if(!workerQueue.isEmpty())
                {
                    Runnable r = workerQueue.poll();
                    r.run();
                }

            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

The Test method I wrote is like below

```
static public void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{

    ClassA a1 = new ClassA();
    ClassA a2 = new ClassA();
    ClassA a3 = new ClassA();
    ClassA a4 = new ClassA();
    ClassA a5 = new ClassA();
    ClassA a6 = new ClassA();

    ThreadPool tp = new ThreadPool(5);

    tp.submit(a1);
    tp.submit(a2);
    tp.submit(a3);
    tp.submit(a4);
    tp.submit(a5);
    ///////////////
    tp.submit(a6);
    tp.shutdown();

}
```

But the program is never ending, its running always and I have to stop it manually in eclipse. But if I add a simple System.out.print("") in my method shutdown, its working perfrectly(the Program is ended after the execution of all the threads).

Can you please tell me why its working with the sysout and why its not working with out it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two major problems with your code:

1. You are using an implementation of `Queue` that's not synchronized in a multithread environment. This leads to a [Race Condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) when multiple threads insert/remove from the queue. Please consider using something like:

   `workerQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue()`
2. You run some very tight loops, one in your `Worker.run()` method where you're not checking for NPE and not allowing for some "cooldown", and another one in `shutdown()`:

   `while (isrunning) {
       ...
       Runnable r = workerQueue.poll();
       r.run();
       ...
   }`

   This, coupled with 1, leads to the `Queue` being emptied without properly updating the size info: ie. `isEmpty()` returns `false` but `poll()` returns null. Your program will become stuck in a loop. This doesn't happen when you add `System.out.print()` due to different timing specific to your configuration (it can continue to fail in other environments - especially where there are more than 6 cpu cores available).

Comment: I changed the workerQueue to ConcurrentLinkedQueue, but now the problem is that sometimes there is no output only or just few of the output comes. It seems like the the program is ending before thethreads are completed. Can you please suggest how to resolve the problem ?

Comment: If the main thread exits then all child threads are closed. You could keep a count of busy/idle threads and wait for all of them to become idle before exiting the main thread. Keep in mind that updating/reading the count should happen in a synchonized manner!

Comment: I am not sure I got your logic, Can you please show a small snippet on how can I Implement the shutdown logic  ?

Comment: You could have a counter in your `ThreadPool` called `idleWorkers`. On each `Worker.run()` you would decrement it if `workerQueue.poll()` contained a `Runnable` and increment it back up when `run()`finishes. You would then check it in `shutdown()`: `while(isRunning && (idleWorkers < poolSize)) {..}`